# Indexing probable column classes in a data.frame

Tags: r, regex, loops, dataframe

This question is more for curiosity than anything else. I already know how to apply the classes to a data frame by column, but what I'm looking for is a simpler way to show what the probable class is/could be for testing purposes.

Yes, there are things that already do this in the tidyverse, but in finding a better way to do these steps it may help me with other functions and implementations.

### Desired outcome:

Return a data.frame of 1-row where the matched class/regex name is inserted rather than the value or the logical from the checks(see below)

#### fake data

So lets say we have a mixed-bag of read-in data from an unknown source... and it comes into R after our parsing as all character classes (I've reproduced from base datasets:

```
usa_a <- structure(
 list(
  states = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California"),
  Murder = c(13.2, 10, 8.1, 8.8, 9), 
  Assault = c(236L, 263L, 294L, 190L, 276L), 
  UrbanPop = c(58L, 48L, 80L, 50L, 91L),
  Rape = c(21.2, 44.5, 31, 19.5, 40.6), 
  log = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
  fracs = c(113.953488372093, 74.4186046511628, 
            109.302325581395, 53.4883720930233, 
            55.8139534883721), 
  mix_bag = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
              "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout")
             ), 
  .Names = c("states", "Murder", "Assault", "UrbanPop", 
             "Rape", "log", "fracs", "mix_bag"),
  row.names = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
              "California"), 
  class = "data.frame")
```

Force all to characters for our purposes

```
usa_a <- usa_a %>% mutate_all(as.character)
str(usa_a)
$ states  : chr "Alabama"
$ Murder  : chr "13.2"
$ Assault : chr "236"
$ UrbanPop: chr "58"
$ Rape    : chr "21.2"
$ log     : chr "TRUE"
$ fracs   : chr "113.953488372093"
$ mix_bag : chr "Mazda RX4"
```

Now to determine/classify/append the class types I'm going to use regex for validations:

```
rgx.pats <- list(
  numeric = "^(\\d){1,}(\\.(\\d){1,})?",
  logical = "^(TRUE|FALSE)$",
  character = "(?!^[(\\d){1,}(\\.(\\d){1,})?|(TRUE|FALSE)]+$)^.+$"
)
```

this is the question... am I missing something obvious and overthinking this / what's an easier or better approach...outside of tidyverse.

#### Request:

If you're solution uses data.table please explain as you would to an infant...

#### Here's the function as-is..

```
class_idx <- mapply(function(x){
    a <- lapply(names(rgx.pats), function(i){
        if(all(stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, rgx.pats[[i]]))){
            i
        }else{
            FALSE
        }
    })
}, usa_a) %>% {
    d <- as.data.frame(.)
    dd <- sapply(colnames(d), function(i){
        which(!mapply(is.logical,d[[i]]))
    })
    as.data.frame(mapply(function(j, y){
        d[j,y]
    }, dd, names(dd)))
}

class_idx
    states  Murder Assault UrbanPop    Rape     log   fracs   mix_bag
1 character numeric numeric  numeric numeric logical numeric character
```

So as you see, it works, I just think i'm falling into a bad habit of looping when it's not needed and can't think of another approach. All feedback/ideas appreciated.

Comment: I understand you're trying your own implementation, but FYI there is `utils::type.convert()`. You may have a look at its [C source here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/utils/src/io.c#L629)

Comment: utils solution slipped my mind and thank you for the link; this will help.